# Adding/generating content automatically in Vim

Tags: loops, vim, text, editing

I have a huge list of numbers and I would like to add content on the end of each line. It's something like this:

Before:

```
123123
123123
13234
124125
12634
5234
```

After:

```
123123, 1
123123, 2
13234, 3
124125, 4
12634, 5
5234, 6
```

A couple of points:

1. I know that `:range s/oldpattern/newpattern/` will substitute the oldpattern by the new one.
2. I know that `for i in range(begin, end) | something | endfor` can generate those extra numbers.

However, I don't know if it's possible to combine them to do what I want (or if there's a different way to do it). Does anybody knows how can I add those extra values automatically? I'm quite sure that it's possible using Vim, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by visually selecting the area then typing

```
:s/$/\=', '.(line('.')-line("'<")+1)<CR>
```

(range is added automatically when you type `:` from visual mode). Visual mode is needed to get `line("'<")` thing, if you are fine with typing line number in place of it use any range.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do

```
:%!nl
:%s/\v^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*)$/\2, \1/g
```

nl will (by default) skip numbering empty lines

Or as a oneliner

```
:exec "%!nl"|%s/\v^\s*(\d+)\s+(.*)$/\2, \1/g
```

Comment: Note that `nl` does not number blank lines, so it may be necessary to use `nl -ba`, depending on the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%!awk '{print $0", "NR}'
```

or

```
:%!perl -lpe '$_.=", $."'
```